# How do you refer to something in APA-style that is not submitted to be published?

Tags: publication-process, apa-style

I'm writing a paper in APA-style. At the end of it, I have my references. There is this one paper (actually an internship report) that I refer to, but it hasn't been submitted for publication. How should I write this down?

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic. Although questions about the [publication-process specific to cogsci/psych are on-topic](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/152/29), this is just a general and easy-to-search question about the APA style. We [do not want to become a reference site](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/320/what-are-the-major-changes-in-the-apa-publication-manual-from-5th-to-6th-edition#comment542_320) for APA style. Also, I believe this does not meet standards of [initial research](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/66/29)

Comment: This question might do well on academia.stackexchange.com, no?

Comment: @Jeff that would be a better fit that cogsci, in my opinion. But we should check with their mods.

Comment: Just my opinion: I don't mind having questions about APA style on this site. The site needs more questions; Questions about APA style are relevant to the research process in psychology. The site is likely to contain experts who are able to answer such questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually citations of [gray literature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_literature) should be avoided. If, however, it is necessary, the APA suggests to provide as much information as possible (see, for instance, the [APA style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2009/08/referencing-gray-literature-in-apa-style.html)). For specific style suggestions, see, for instance, [a library handout summarizing the APA guides on gray literature](http://www.nova.edu/library/dils/teachinghandouts/apa/APA_6th_ed.pdf).